# Are ARIA roles limited to certain elements?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

While validating my website with validator.w3.org containing this markup:

```
<h4 role="button" aria-controls="panel-1">...</h4>
<ul id="panel-1" role="tabpanel">...</ul>
```

... I got the following errors:

`Error: Bad value button for attribute role on element h4.`

`Error: Bad value tabpanel for attribute role on element ul.`

Of course, both ARIA roles exist. Changing both elements from `<h4>` resp. `<ul>` to `<div>` resolves the error. But: What rule did I break? I skimmed through https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#roles and MDN and don't see any limits as to which elements may receive which role.

Is there something I didn't see or is the validator too strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating the [Second rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second).

> Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to.
>
> For example: Developer wants to build a heading that's a tab.
>
> Do not do this:
>
> ```
> <h2 role=tab>heading tab</h2>
> ```
>
> Do this:
>
> ```
> <div role=tab><h2>heading tab</h2></div>
> ```

In your case, you should put a `<button>` inside the `<h4>` and avoid the use of `role` entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that one. So the role attribute only makes sense within <div> or <span>? I think this should be communicated more clearly within the documentation of the roles.

Comment: Oh, and they used my case as an example for rule 6:
https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#nativesemantics
That's all not very consistent and well-documented.

Comment: @wortwart — That tells you what it does, it doesn't say it is a good idea. In fact it demonstrates that the heading semantics are thrown away which is what makes it a bad idea.

Comment: It's not so much about violating rule #2 of ARIA because the syntax checker doesn't care about that. What you are violating is HTML syntax. The spec for h1, h2, h3 says the only valid roles for those elements is "heading" (which is the default and you should **not** set), "none", "presentation", or "tab".  See https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-h1-h6. When in doubt, just go to the official html spec, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/, look up your element, then check the "Accessibility considerations:" section "for authors". That will take you to the table I mentioned in my first link.

Comment: @slugolicious: Thank you, https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#docconformance is the documentation that I was searching.
So, https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/ has an example with an unmarked HTML error.